# Can't create thread because "Takes 1 positional argument but 4 given" only when I give it a string longer than 1

Tags: python, python-3.x, multithreading, python-multithreading

I am making a chat server in python. I have been creating threads fine so far, but when I try to create one, with the argument of a username, it fails with the above error - but only when the username is more than 1 character.

If I give it the username "A", it works fine, but the username "Alex" gives the error. How do I fix this?

They are in the same class.

I create the thread with

`Thread(target=Main.ManageClientHighLevel, args=(Username)).start()`

And the start of that function is:

`def ManageClientHighLevel(Username):`

How do I fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Thread`'s `args` argument expects an `Iterable`, so you will have to provide your single argument in a `tuple`:

```py
Thread(target=Main.ManageClientHighLevel, args=(Username,)).start()
```

Otherwise, it will handle your single provided string as an `Iterable` and iterate over each character.

Answer (score 1):

You must convert Username to a tuple: `(Username,)` since a string is an interable, which means that "username" would actually be considered as "(u,s,e,r,n,a,m,e)".